# NodeJS - Nock doesn't intercept request made using the `request/request` module

Tags: node.js, request, nock

In my tests, i'm trying to intercept HTTP request made by the `request/request`. But it doesn't work. When I use `http.request()` nock works perfectly.
Here is an exemple :

```
it('A test case', function() {
    nock('http://www.google.com')
    .get('/')
    .reply(200, { response: 'Hello from Nock!' });

  request('http://www.google.com/', function(err, res, body) {
    console.log(body); // It displays the actual response :(
  });
});
```

Any insight ?!

**EDIT:**
After all, It a proxy related problem.

Comment: How did you set up your test for requests made through a proxy?

Comment: How did you fix it? I have similar issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use request-debug module from npm.

```
var request = require('request');

require('request-debug')(request);

require('request-debug')(request, function(type, data, r) {
    // put your request or response handling logic here
});
```

In the request object should be your requests data.

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear. I want `nock` to intercept the request made by the `request/request` module.
When i use `http.request`, `nock` works fine buy NOT with `request/request`.